# Access: UPDATE column with values from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to Update column1 in table1 with values from column2 from table2 with a criteria in table2.
This is very confusing so here is my SQL code, maybe then you understand what I mean...

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE table1 SET column1 = table2.column2 WHERE table2.ID = 1"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

This code isn't working as expected, so I need your help...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a connection (join) between table1 and table2? Or do you really want to set column1 for all rows to a single value?

Comment: Actually I want to have the same value in table1.column1 as in table2.column2 where the ID row of the tables are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join your tables, and then you can set the value:

```
UPDATE table1 
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
SET table1.column1 = table2.column2
WHERE table2.ID = 1    -- not sure if you actually want to keep this criterium
```